# What is canon/in continuity in DC Rebirth?

Tags: dc, comics, canon, green-lantern, continuity

Also, how does DC rebirth affect the continuity of green lantern?

Comment: Rebirth seems to be a mess - Wiki says there was Doctor Manhattan involved, like what the heck?! If anyone could clarify what Rebirth actually is?

Comment: See here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138759/did-barry-allen-reboot-the-comics-in-2011-giving-origin-to-the-current-dc-univer/

Answer (score 1):

As with almost every reboot, there is almost certainly no set list of what is in and what is out. Until something is explicitly mentioned as having happened in a book or some other canonical source, the answer to the question "did this happen?" is almost certainly "maybe". It will take one writer or another deciding that they need event XYZ to make a story make sense, or contrariwize they need event ABC to go away so he can tell his story.

Rebirth, as with the story Green Lantern Rebirth from which it got its name, seems to be doing a good job of not quite restarting everything from scratch, but "revealing" that certain facts and assumption are not true, and that certain new events help fix problems of the past.  Example - we learned that Hal Jordan did not in fact kill all of those Green Lanterns, as opposed to changing history so said event never even happened.

So far there have been no major changes to the origins of most heroes (Wonder Woman is going through a bit of an Everything You Know Is Wrong moment), just changes in mindset. So no changes to the GL history, recent or long term.  Same for Batman, just a number of bat-characters returning to working with them.

It's not as much that it's "a mess" as much as every plot thread set up in the launch book has been picked up yet.  We probably won't see much mention of the JSA or the Legion until next year, once the get the main titles on an even keel.

And let's just not even talk about the whle Watchmen thing at all, eh?

Comment: Thanks for answer! I was actually thinking about starting out New 52 properly (all the lines, al the characters), but this reboot-not-being-a-reboot threw me off. I think I'll just stick with Injustice for now.

Comment: The New 52 had enough fits and starts, as well as a couple clear choices to change in mid-stream, that trying to read all of it might be more work than fun. The Rebirth titles, OTOH, have all been pretty damned good.  If you know enough about the characters' histories, you could start with them, with maybe a run-up thanks to Wiki.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused - I thought New 52 was an actual tabula rasa and Rebirth is additional characters loading. How can Rebirth be easier to start?

Comment: The new 52 came very close to a full restart, except the continuity of Batman and the GL corps, DC's biggest books at the time, went through largely unchanged. 

The central idea of the New 52 is that the history of heroes on Earth was now only about 5 years.  So Superman, Flash, etc, only started appearing piblicly on Earth about five years before "now".  Batman was hastily explained to have started earlier, but in the shadows, only going public closer to the time of the rest.

Comment: I watched the new Justice League animations and The Flashpoint Paradox, so I have some general understanding of things. Did Hellblazer change as well? I just finished *Death of the Family* and the series being in 5 or so different comic books really threw me off. I thought I'd start Hellblazer - would I need to jump around different series much?

Comment: The comics in the New52 are not even canon to other comics in the New52 so... yeah... there is no point in even trying...

Answer (score 0):

When they get the ten years that were stolen back, things will start to fall into place. Wally said in Rebirth that it wasn't Flashpoint -  it was longer ago than that; I think 1986 post crisis beginning was when it got dark, hence Wally saying they changed. Watchmen ended same time as Crisis of Infinite Earths, it's pretty eerily convenient.