# Is it revealed in Rebirth why this character interfered with the DC universe?

Tags: dc, comics, the-new-52, dc-rebirth

I don't really read much comic books, but I really want to know. 
In the relaunch of the DC universe, the *Rebirth* series, has it been revealed yet why this happened?

> Dr. Manhattan removed 10 years from their timeline, which resulted in the New 52 series.

Why did he do this?

Comment: Related background reading (not a duplicate): [Did Barry Allen reboot the DC continuity in 2011 creating the DC Universe known as “the New 52?”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138759/70236)

Comment: We don't know yet - current issues of BATMAN and THE FLASH are investigating this (but probably won't provide definitive answers; it's a 4 issue crossover between two books, not a mega-event.)

Comment: Because DC hates Alan Moore.

Comment: The present series DOOMSDAY CLOCK is expected to address this.